# Too few arguments to function LibraryClearanceTableSeeder

Tags: laravel

I have created a StudentTableSeeder to seed my  Students table, while seeding for each student, I want to generate the student's library and fee clearances whenever a student is created by the StudentTableSeeder. I get this error "FatalThrowableError  :Too few arguments to function LibraryClearanceTableSeeder::run(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

This is StudentTableSeeder code

```
use App\Models\Student;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class StudentsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

     protected $students = [
        [
            'id'                    =>  1,
            'firstname'             =>  'Emmanuel',
            'middlename'            =>  'kwame',
            'lastname'              =>  'Agyapong',
            'index_no'              =>  'ANU16280111',
            'nationality'           =>  0,
            'regular_or_weekend'    =>  1,
            'image'                 =>  null,
            'course_id'             =>  1,
        ],
  ];


   public function run()
{
     foreach ($this->students as $index => $student)
      {
        $result = Student::create($student);
        if (!$result) {
            $this->command->info("Insert failed at record $index.");
            return;
        }
        $this->call(LibraryClearanceTableSeeder::class)->run($students['student_id']);
    }
    $this->command->info('Inserted '.count($this->students). ' records');
   }
 }
```

This is my LibraryClearanceTableSeeder

```
use App\Models\Library;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class LibraryClearanceTableSeeder extends Seeder
 {

  public function run($studentid)
  {
    DB::table('libraries')->create([
        'student_id' => $studentid,
        'borrowed'  => 0,
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use static function in seeder

This is StudentTableSeeder code

```
use App\Models\Student;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class StudentsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

     protected $students = [
        [
            'id'                    =>  1,
            'firstname'             =>  'Emmanuel',
            'middlename'            =>  'kwame',
            'lastname'              =>  'Agyapong',
            'index_no'              =>  'ANU16280111',
            'nationality'           =>  0,
            'regular_or_weekend'    =>  1,
            'image'                 =>  null,
            'course_id'             =>  1,
        ],
  ];


   public function run()
{
     foreach ($this->students as $index => $student)
      {
        $result = Student::create($student);
        if (!$result) {
            $this->command->info("Insert failed at record $index.");
            return;
        }
        LibraryClearanceTableSeeder::setLib($student['id']);
    }
    $this->command->info('Inserted '.count($this->students). ' records');
   }
 }
```

This is LibraryClearanceTableSeeder

```
use App\Models\Library;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class LibraryClearanceTableSeeder extends Seeder
 {

  public function run()
  {

  }

  public static function setLib($studentid)
  {
    DB::table('libraries')->create([
        'student_id' => $studentid,
        'borrowed'  => 0,
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was getting badmethodcallexception so i changed create() to insert() in LibraryClearanceTableSeeder and it worked.

```
 public static function setLib($studentid)
 {
   DB::table('libraries')->insert([
    'student_id' => $studentid,
    'borrowed'  => 0,
  ]);
}
```